# How to find values with certain number of decimal places using SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out a way, using SQL, to query for values that go out to, say, 5 or more decimal places. In other words, I want to see only results that have 5+ decimal places (e.g. 45.324754) - the numbers before the decimal are irrelevant, however, I still need to see the full number. Is this possible? Any help if appreciated.

Comment: Sure. What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Will try these solutions on Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your DBMS supports `FLOOR` and your datatype conversion model supports this multiplication, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE FLOOR(Num*100000)!=Num*100000
```

This has the advantage of not requiring a conversion to a string datatype.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server, you can specify:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Value <> ROUND(Value,4,1);
```

For an ANSI method, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Value <> CAST(Value*100000.0 AS INT) / 100000.0;
```

Although this method might cause an overflow if you're working with large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select val
from tablename
where length(substr(val,instr(val, '.')+1)) > 5
```

This is a way to do it in oracle using `substr` and `instr`

Answer (score 0):

I imagine most DBMSs have a `round` function

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourCol <> ROUND(YourCol,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE YourValue LIKE '%._____%';
```

Comment: This would also match `1.00000` which is presumably not what is needed as that is a function of datatype not value.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use below decode statement to identify maximum decimal present in database table

```
SELECT max(decode(INSTR(val,'.'), 0, 0, LENGTH(SUBSTR(val,INSTR(val,'.')+1)))) max_decimal 
FROM tablename A;
```